# Error log inside thread not working sometime

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool

I am calling following method inside thread. inside method i have written logs which writes some variable values in notepad file.

Problem : Sometime last log of method do not log anything. ie last line not exucuting sometime. i am not able to understand problem. please guide me if there are issue somewhere.
**This is web application hosted in iis server.**

**Function :**

```
public bool ResetEmployeeAssignedCoursesByRole()
    {
        bool bReturn = false;
        DbTransactionHelper dbTransactionHelper = new DbTransactionHelper();
        dbTransactionHelper.BeginTransaction();
        try
        {
            // this line execuete fine
            ErrorLog.createRoleLog("Method sp_Reset_EmpAssignedCoursesByRole  Started " + this.RoleID + " Course ID " + this.CourseID + " External Message " + sMessage);
            StringBuilder sbQueryEmployeeCourse = new StringBuilder();
            sbQueryEmployeeCourse.Append(" set @roleID = " + roleID + "; ");
            sbQueryEmployeeCourse.Append(" set @courseID = " + courseID + "; ");
            sbQueryEmployeeCourse.Append(" set @inActiveReason = " + inActiveReason + "; ");
            sbQueryEmployeeCourse.Append(" set @lastRecordUpdateSource = " + lastRecordUpdateSource + "; ");
            sbQueryEmployeeCourse.Append(" call sp_Reset_EmpAssignedCoursesByRole (@roleID, @courseID, @inActiveReason, @lastRecordUpdateSource); ");

            DataTable dtEmployeeCourse = dbTransactionHelper.GetDataTable(BusinessUtility.GetString(sbQueryEmployeeCourse), CommandType.Text, null
                    );
            dbTransactionHelper.CommitTransaction();
            bReturn = true;


            // this line not execuete sometime.
            ErrorLog.createRoleLog("Method sp_Reset_EmpAssignedCoursesByRole  Ended " + this.RoleID + " Course ID " + this.CourseID + " External Message " + sMessage);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorLog.createRoleLog("Add Role ID " + BusinessUtility.GetString(roleID));
            dbTransactionHelper.RollBackTransaction();
            ErrorLog.createRoleLog("Add Course ID " + BusinessUtility.GetString(courseID));
            ErrorLog.createRoleLog(ex.ToString());
        }
        return bReturn;
    }
```

**Calls method like below :**

```
Thread t = new Thread(ResetEmployeeAssignedCoursesByRole);
t.Start();
```

**FUNCTION createRoleLog :**

```
public static void createRoleLog(string errorMessage, int empHdrID = 0)
    {
        try
        {
            //string path = BusinessUtility.GetString(AppConfig.GetAppConfigValue("LogsDiractory")) + "Log" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + ".txt";
            string path = BusinessUtility.GetString(ErrorLog.ErrorLogPath) + "RoleLog" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + ".txt";
            if (BusinessUtility.GetString(AppConfig.GetAppConfigValue("LogError")).ToString().ToUpper() == "TRUE")
            {
                if (!File.Exists(path))
                {
                    StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path);
                    sw.Close();
                }
                //using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = System.IO.File.AppendText(path))
                //{
                //    sw.WriteLine("-------- " + DateTime.Now + " --------");
                //    sw.WriteLine(errorMessage);
                //    sw.WriteLine("------------------------");
                //    sw.Close();
                //}




                if (!IsFileLocked(new FileInfo(path)))
                {
                    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                    {
                        using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream))
                        {
                            if (empHdrID != 0)
                            {
                                sw.WriteLine("-------- [empHdrID: " + empHdrID + "] " + DateTime.Now + " --------");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                sw.WriteLine("-------- " + DateTime.Now + " --------");
                            }

                            sw.WriteLine(errorMessage);
                            sw.WriteLine("------------------------");
                            sw.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {

                }


            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //throw ex;
        }
    }
```

**Last line of function which not execution sometime is :**

** this line not execuete sometime.**

```
        ErrorLog.createRoleLog("Method sp_Reset_EmpAssignedCoursesByRole  Ended " + this.RoleID + " Course ID " + this.CourseID + " External Message " + sMessage);
```

Comment: Please do not compose SQL queries by string concatenation.
Use parameterized queries, otherwise you open yourself to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: did you already debug it? execution won't just stop unless the worker thread is killed, and even then a ThreadAbortException can be expected. If the "Method sp_Reset_EmpAssignedCoursesByRole" part does end up in the log, then perhaps it hits `catch` instead (a class member like `lastRecordUpdateSource` may have been changed by another thread etc...), place a breakpoint there.

Comment: Please show the implementation of `createRoleLog`, since you have that method both inside the try block and the catch block, *one* of them should at least execute, but if you find no trace of it in the log then most likely there is a bug in its implementation.

Comment: ok i will do care of that. any idea on issue i am getting

Comment: @Dragonthoughts while this one is an especially creative way of defying parametrization I haven't seen before :)

Comment: @Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen  i have added createRoleLog implementation.

Comment: Where `IsFileLocked` is used, place a breakpoint on the empty `else` below, and on the empty catch. At the moment, you're ignoring any exceptions there, which is not helpful for debugging. If it is locked at the time you try to log something, the procedure should retry-and-timeout, or write to a new file.

Comment: @dlatikay : if it goes into exception part. there also a log is written. and i dont find any error.
and database things seems working as data is saving in tables.

Comment: ok. I mean inside the `createRoleLog`, you have a catch but it does nothing. That would just silently fail. Put a breakpoint there, remove the try...catch from within `createRoleLog`. The (currently commented-out) `throw ex` is of no use, it just obscures your call stack.

Comment: @dlatikay : yes i am adding some log there. thanks for your suggestion. hope i can see something after adding.